# C# expression evaluates to a namespace

Tags: c#, expression

MSDN docs state "An expression is a fragment of code that can be evaluated to a single value, object, method, or namespace."

Could someone please explain what it means for an expression to evaluate to a namespace - how can that be?

edit: fixed typo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how the grammar is defined. Look at:

```
System.String
```

is an expression containing a dot operator that operates on a couple different expressions. `System` alone is considered an expression. An expression can be as simple as a single identifier or literal (hint: it's defined recursively.)

> #### Expressions (C# 3.5 spec section §7.1: Expression classifications)
>
> An expression is classified as one of the following:
> ...
> A namespace. An expression with this classification can only appear as the left hand side of a member-access (§7.5.4). In any other context, an expression classified as a namespace causes a compile-time error.

Not being able to use it as, say, an argument to a method doesn't disqualify it as being considered an expression.

Comment: Thanks for the education - Guess I was thinking to literal!

Answer (score 3):

On [this page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173144.aspx) it says:

> However, **although a namespace name is
>   classified as an expression, it does
>   not evaluate to a value and therefore
>   can never be the final result of any
>   expression. You cannot pass a
>   namespace name to a method parameter,
>   or use it in a new expression, or
>   assign it to a variable. You can only
>   use it as a sub-expression in a larger
>   expression.** The same is true for types
>   (as distinct from System..::.Type 
>   objects), method group names (as
>   distinct from specific methods), and
>   event  add and  remove accessors.

So in reality you can't really do anything with a namespace being a expression it always work in the same way there is nothing dynamic about it that you can influence but for the parser a namespace has to be something :). The reason it is an expression is due to the grammar of the C# language that's used to parse the code during the compilation process. It consists out of statements, expressions, operators etc... so in the case of System.Guid yourGuid = System.Guid.NewGuid() the System part would be a expression containing a namespace, the . would be an opperator and the Guid would be a type to the C# parser.

Comment: The page I was on didn't have that part but I'm reading that page now - ty.

Comment: Ok, I added the link for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
foo = System;
```

`System` evaluates to a namespace.

(Of course, this won't compile, because you can't assign a namespace to a variable, but you get the idea.)

Comment: You can actually do that in a using, though.

Comment: Exactly, using statements are about the only place where you can successfully use a namespace expression. But I wanted to show an example that might fire the particular error given.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an expression like this:

```
using OutlookStuff = Microsoft.Office.Outlook.This.Is.Really.Long.Isnt.It;
```

and then be able to use the expression later in code.  This can be useful when there is namespace contention like if you have a class like MailItem or something that is common across multiple namespaces.

So you can now do this:

```
var mailItem = new OutlookStuff.MailItem();
```

**EDIT** I think Mehrdad's answer is the more correct answer, but I thought this was worth noting.

Comment: wouldn't this alias have to point to a class though?
using Timer=System.Windows.Forms.Timer;
private readonly Timer _clock;
...

Comment: Ah I got ya - The alias points to a namespace! I've only pointed them to specific types.